# Bootstrap 3 - Open model and get id or data atribute (both ways ok)

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have two div, have open the same modal window:

```
<div id="regulatorias" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalReguOpor" data-alert="regulatorias">
       Content...
</div>

<div id="oportunidades" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalReguOpor" data-alert="oportunidades">
       Content...
</div>
```

When invoking the event that opens the modal, I want to get the id atribute or the value of the data-alert, of the div  which I am clicking.

```
$("#myModalReguOpor").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  // here I want to get the id or data-alert value, about the div that i'm clicking
});
```

How could make it?

Thanks,

Comment: cant you pass a parameter to the function? Like `function(element) { return element.id }`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModalReguOpor').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('id');
        alert(id);
     });
});
```

I would suggest to replace `id` with `data-attribute` like `data-id="regulatorias"` in modal trigger button

```
<div data-id="regulatorias" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalReguOpor" data-alert="regulatorias">
       Content...
</div>
```

and in JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModalReguOpor').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        alert(id);
     });
});
```